# Implementing a long running Business logic in MVVM without UI lockup

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm

I am currently practicing the MVVM pattern, and I'd like to implement a UI which won't freeze for long running logic in my Business layer. Let me explain below.

VIEW:
I currently have a progress bar which should fill up as the progress of operation in the backend goes on.

```
            <ProgressBar x:Name="prgFeedback" Height="25" Margin="10,20,10,40" Value="{Binding ProgressValue}" />
```

VIEWMODEL:
Currently I've implemented a basic view model with three properties that is bound to the UI.

```
class MyViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = (sender, e) => { };

    private string _InputPath { get; set; }
    private string _OutputPath { get; set; }
    private double _ProgressValue { get; set; }


    public string InputPath
    {
        get { return _InputPath; }
        set
        {
            if (_InputPath != value)
            {
                _InputPath = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("InputPath")); 
            }
        }
    }

    public string OutputPath
    {
        get { return _OutputPath; }
        set
        {
            if (_OutputPath != value)
            {
                _OutputPath = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("OutputPath"));
            }
        }

    }

    public double ProgressValue
    {
        get { return _ProgressValue; }
        set
        {
            if (_ProgressValue != value)
            {
                _ProgressValue = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ProgressValue"));
            }
        }
    }

    public ICommand Button_Command{get;set;}

    public MyModel()
    {

        modelobj = new MyModel();
    }


    public void Button_Run()
    {
        ProgressValue = 0;
        InputPath = modelobj.DialogGetInput();

        //Get output here 
        thing.ProgressChanged += new EventHandler<WorkerEventArgs>(OnProgressChanged);
        OutputPath = modelobj.FlowLogic();
    }

    private void OnProgressChanged(object sender, WorkerEventArgs e)
    {
        ProgressValue = e.Progress;
    }
}
```

Here I play to move the Command to the public constructor so that my application will run the loop from start up of the application. But for now It's bound to a button on the UI.

MODEL: So here is the stripped down version of the model I hope this is enough to give you an idea about the operation I'm planning on executing.

```
public class MyModel
{


    #region Properties
    public  string OutputPath
    { get
        {
            return _OutputPath;
        }
        set
        { if (_OutputPath != value)
            {
                _OutputPath = value;
            }
        }
    }
    private  string _OutputPath{ get;  set; }

    public  string InputPath
    {
         get
        {
            return _InputPath;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_InputPath != value)
            {
                _InputPath = value;
            }
        }
    }

    private string _InputPath { get; set; }
    #endregion

   public MyModel()
    {
    }

    #region Helpers

    public event EventHandler<WorkerEventArgs> ProgressChanged;

    private void NotifyProgress(double current, double max)
    {
        if (ProgressChanged != null)
        {
            double progress = (current/max)*100 ; 
            ProgressChanged(this, new WorkerEventArgs(progress));
        }
    }
    #endregion  
    #region Logic
    public string DialogGetInput()
    {
            //Logic to get a path for the File containing the ID's

            return path;
    }


    private string Generate_Date_Info(string ID)
    {
        string tolog = "";

                    //Logic to get date for each ID from Database.

        return tolog;
    }

    public string FlowLogic()
    {


        string tolog="";
                    int i = 0; // used to get the current index from the list of ID's
                     int k = 0; // used to get the total count of ID's from file.


                foreach(string ID in IDs)  //IDs will contain all the IDs read from the file
                    {
                        tolog +=Generate_runs(ID);
                        tolog +=Generate_ID_Change(ID);
                        tolog +=Generate_Date_Info(ID);
                    }

                    //Write 'tolog' to a file using StreamWriter
        NotifyProgress(int i,int k);
        return OutputPath;



    }

    private string Generate_ID_Change(string ID)
    {

        string tolog = "";
        tolog += Environment.NewLine;

            //Logic to retrive addidtional data from Database

        return tolog;
    }

    private string Generate_runs(string ID)
    {
     string tolog = "";
     tolog += Environment.NewLine;

            //Logic to retrive Data from Database
     return tolog;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

And as another article had pointed me to I used the Worker Event to notify my UI about the change in progress below.

```
    public class WorkerEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public double Progress { get; private set; }

    public WorkerEventArgs(double progress)
    {
        Progress = progress;
    }
}
```

When I run this on step by step debug mode, I can see my Model calling the event, which triggers a value change on the ViewModel which I then see calling the PropertyChanged, but I do not see my UI update it's progress bar.

How Do I have the UI be responsive as I am running this particular application.

Comment: Too much code. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, in your model and ViewModel, there are private properties which are unnecessary. They should be simple fields. And you can further simplify INotifyPropertyChanged implementation; Google it.

Comment: You have to do your work on a background thread, and you cannot update the UI too quickly. There are reams on these subjects out there, available freely. You should do a little research on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run the long running operation in its own thread. Something like:

```
    public DoLongRunningOperation()
    {

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {

                // Do some really cpu intense stuff.. 

                Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, new Action(() =>
                {
                    ProgressValue = i;
                }));
            }
        });
    }
```

By calling the dispatcher you can jump back to the main tread.

Comment: With INPC properties you don't have to use the dispatcher. Bindings automatically do that for you.

Comment: So this indeed does work for me and the UI updates on time, I have modified this on my model and it works . I'm still quite new but doesn't this bring about a problem if I create a new instance of my model on the viewmodel wouldn't it bring about multiple threads? Or would there be a more structured way to implement such a situation ?